# How much gluten flour do I need to add?

Tags: baking, flour, pizza

Ill spare everyone the boring details and just say that im trying to mimick a pizza at home. I know that the original pizza uses a flour with 15% protein but I can't find that flour available. Instead, I'm using bread flour that has 12.7% protein.

I have gluten flour that has 75%    protein. How much gluten flour would I need to add to the bread flour to get an overall 15% protein level?

Comment: How much flour total does your recipe call for?

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42055, I would even be inclined to see it as duplicate. Or are there differences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create my own high-gluten flour by mixing vital wheat gluten and bread/AP flour?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42055/create-my-own-high-gluten-flour-by-mixing-vital-wheat-gluten-and-bread-ap-flour)

Comment: The answer in the duplicate question explains the general math, so get your recipe, some scrsp paper or a calculator and you'll be fine. Enjoy your pizza!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If x is the fraction by weight of bread flour, then:

```
0.127x + 0.75(1-x) = 0.15
0.75 - 0.623x = 0.15
0.6 = 0.623x
x = .963
```

So, use 96% bread flour and 4% of your high-gluten flour, by weight.