# Can I mix all-purpose flour with high-gluten flour to make bread flour?

Tags: bread, flour

Basically of the opposite of [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42055/create-my-own-high-gluten-flour-by-mixing-vital-wheat-gluten-and-bread-ap-flour).

I'm writing during the 2020 pandemic, and bread flour is sold out everywhere because everyone (including me) is entertaining themselves at home by making bread. I did manage to find "high-gluten flour", which according to [Epicurious](https://www.epicurious.com/expert-advice/bread-ingredients-guide-to-flours-for-homemade-dough-article) seems to be more or less the same as bread flour but with a higher protein content:

> Unbleached all-purpose has the lowest amount of protein, usually around 10.5%. Bread flour contains about 12 to 12.7%. High-gluten and whole-wheat flours have about 14% protein.

My recipe calls for white bread flour. (I'm making sourdough at 80% hydration, in case it matters.) Can I get there by mixing this high-gluten flour with AP flour? What proportions should I use? Any pitfalls I should be aware of?

Comment: Just as a comment, I make a sourdough at 66% hydration with a Canadian flour billed at 14.9% protein. I like that better than the results I get at 12/13%. Perhaps it’s worth making your recipe with the high-gluten flour once and see what you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can mix them at basically a 1:1 ratio to achieve a flour with roughly 12% protein content (mimicking bread flour).

Bread flour is milled from hard spring wheat, which has a higher protein content than the hard winter wheat used in all-purpose flour. Protein adds strength to dough and enables loaves of bread to rise high.

Mixing them together to achieve a roughly 12% protein content will ensure you don't end up with a bread that's way too dense/soft or rises far too much/little, basically.

There's no issues mixing flours, and in fact this can be a great way to create the mixture you need when it's sold out (such as during this pandemic).